# simple for loop java reactor post flatmap

Tags: java, reactor, flatmap

My problem is that I do a post request to get the total number of elements in my db and I need to do a for loop until I reach that number integer division 10.

My current not working code

```
protected Mono<List<Long>> getAllSubscriptionIds(ProductCode productCode) {
    List<Long> subscriptionIds = new ArrayList<>();

    String body = "{\n" +
            " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
            " \"pagination\": {\n" +
            "     \"offset\": 0,\n" +
            "     \"limit\": 10" +
            "\n  }\n" +
            " }";
    //first post where I get the number of elements in my db
    return restClient.post(
                    "https://" + url,
                    buildRequiredHeaders(),
                    body,
                    String.class
            )
            .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
            .flatMap(response -> {
                log.debug(response);
                ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>> variable = null;
                try {
                    variable = JsonUtil.fromString(response, new TypeReference<ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>>>() {
                    });
                    log.debug(response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                variable.getPayload().getList().forEach(
                        object-> subscriptionIds.add(object.get("subscriptionId").asLong()));
                //if number of elements > 10
                if(variable.getPayload().getPagination().getResultCount() > 10){
                    //for loop on that number / 10 (so that I can use an offset
                    for (int i = 0; i < variable.getPayload().getPagination().getResultCount() / 10; i++){
                        String bodyI = "{\n" +
                                " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
                                " \"pagination\": {\n" +
                                "     \"offset\": " + (i + 1) * 10 + ",\n" +
                                "     \"limit\": 10\n" +
                                "  }\n" +
                                " }";
                        return restClient.post(
                                        "https://" + url,
                                        buildRequiredHeaders(),
                                        bodyI,
                                        String.class
                                )
                                .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
                                .flatMap(resp -> {
                                    ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>> varia = null;
                                    try {
                                        varia = JsonUtil.fromString(resp, new TypeReference<ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>>>() {
                                        });
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                    }
                                    varia.getPayload().getList().forEach(
                                            object-> subscriptionIds.add(object.get("subscriptionId").asLong()));

                                    return Mono.just(subscriptionIds);
                                });
                    }
                }
                return Mono.just(subscriptionIds);
            });
}
```

I do understand why this does not work (it return inside the for loop) but I don't really understand what alternative can I use to make it work.
I tried an external method but it will still fail. I tried a Mono.zip but I think I tried it wrong.

This is an alternative that I tried but it still does not work.

```
protected Mono<Object> getAllSubscriptionIds(ProductCode productCode) {
this.counter = 0;
List<Long> subscriptionIds = new ArrayList<>();
List<Mono<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

String body = "{\n" +
        " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
        " \"pagination\": {\n" +
        "     \"offset\": 0,\n" +
        "     \"limit\": 10" +
        "\n  }\n" +
        " }";

return restClient.post(
                "https://" + url,
                buildRequiredHeaders(),
                body,
                String.class
        )
        .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
        .flatMap(response -> {
            log.debug(response);
            ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>> variable = null;
            try {
                variable = JsonUtil.fromString(response, new TypeReference<ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>>>() {
                });
                log.debug(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            variable.getPayload().getList().forEach(
                    object-> subscriptionIds.add(object.get("subscriptionId").asLong()));

            if(variable.getPayload().getPagination().getResultCount() > 10){
                for (int i = 0; i < variable.getPayload().getPagination().getResultCount() / 10; i++){
                    resultList.add(Mono.just(i));
                }
            }

            return Mono.zip(resultList, intMono -> {
                this.counter++;
                String bodyI = "{\n" +
                        " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
                        " \"pagination\": {\n" +
                        "     \"offset\": " + this.counter * 10 + ",\n" +
                        "     \"limit\": 10\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        " }";
                return restClient.post(
                                "https://" + url,
                                buildRequiredHeaders(),
                                bodyI,
                                String.class
                        )
                        .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
                        .flatMap(resp -> {
                            ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>> varia = null;
                            try {
                                varia = JsonUtil.fromString(resp, new TypeReference<ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>>>() {
                                });
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                            varia.getPayload().getList().forEach(
                                    object-> subscriptionIds.add(object.get("subscriptionId").asLong()));

                            return Mono.just(subscriptionIds);
                        });
            });
           // return Mono.just(subscriptionIds);
        });
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I got a solution

```
protected Flux<Object> getAllSubscriptionIds(ProductCode productCode) {
    List<Long> subscriptionIds = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();

    String body = "{\n" +
            " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
            " \"pagination\": {\n" +
            "     \"offset\": 0,\n" +
            "     \"limit\": 1000" +
            "\n  }\n" +
            " }";

    return restClient.post(
                    "https://" + url,
                    buildRequiredHeaders(),
                    body,
                    String.class
            )
            .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
            .flatMapMany(response -> {
                log.debug(response);
                ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>> variable = null;
                try {
                    variable = JsonUtil.fromString(response, new TypeReference<ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>>>() {
                    });
                    log.debug(response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                variable.getPayload().getList().forEach(
                        object-> subscriptionIds.add(object.get("subscriptionId").asLong()));

                if(variable.getPayload().getPagination().getResultCount() > 1000){
                        String bodyI = "{\n" +
                                " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
                                " \"pagination\": {\n" +
                                "     \"offset\": " + i.incrementAndGet() * 1000 + ",\n" +
                                "     \"limit\": 1000\n" +
                                "  }\n" +
                                " }";
                        return restClient.post(
                                        "https://" + url,
                                        buildRequiredHeaders(),
                                        bodyI,
                                        String.class
                                )
                                .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
                                .flatMap(resp -> {
                                    return restClient.post(
                                                    "https://" + url,
                                                    buildRequiredHeaders(),
                                                    "{\n" +
                                                            " \"productCodes\": [\"" + productCode.name() + "\"],\n" +
                                                            " \"pagination\": {\n" +
                                                            "     \"offset\": " + i.incrementAndGet() * 1000 + ",\n" +
                                                            "     \"limit\": 1000\n" +
                                                            "  }\n" +
                                                            " }",
                                                    String.class
                                            )
                                            .onErrorMap(err-> new RuntimeException(err.getMessage()))
                                            .flatMap(respI -> {
                                                ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>> varia = null;
                                                try {
                                                    varia = JsonUtil.fromString(respI, new TypeReference<ResponseModel<DataLakeCallResponse<JsonNode>>>() {
                                                    });
                                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                                }
                                                varia.getPayload().getList().forEach(
                                                        object-> subscriptionIds.add(object.get("subscriptionId").asLong()));

                                                return Mono.just(subscriptionIds);
                                            });
                                }).repeat(variable.getPayload().getPagination().getResultCount() / 1000);
                }
                return Mono.just(subscriptionIds);
            });
}
```

Basically I changed the first flatMap to flatMapMany so that inside that I could have a flatMap with a repeat loop. I had to return a Flux instead of my original Mono<List> but since I know it will always result in a Mono<List> anyway I changed original caller to

```
return getAllSubscriptionIds(request.getEventMetadata().getProductCode()).collect(Collectors.reducing((i1, i2) -> i1)).flatMap(responseIds -> {
        List<BillableApiCall> queryResults = dataLakeMapper.getBillableCallsApiCheckIban(
                ((ArrayList<Long>)responseIds.get()),
                DateUtil.toLocalDateEuropeRome(request.getFromDate()),
                DateUtil.toLocalDateEuropeRome(request.getToDate()),
                request.getPagination()
        );
```

So I had to add .collect(Collectors.reducing((i1, i2) -> i1)) (I copy/pasted this so I only guess what it does... it convert the Flux to Mono), and cast my responseIds with ((ArrayList)responseIds.get()).

repeat was not the final solution since it only repeat what's inside the flatMap (it will not repeat the post connected to it) so I had to use a trick... I removed the for loop that was not necessary, I made a post inside my flatMap repeat with another flatMap... The only missing things was to keep track of my index and I was able to find that you can use an AtomicInteger to do that.
It was not an easy task at all but I tested it and it's working.
To recap:

1. flatMapMany with a repeat flatMap inside (repeat only take a long as an argument, so it will repeat until it reach that value and auto-increment... but you cannot use this index for what I understand).
2. Another flatMap inside the flatMap repeat, that's because you cannot do another post call without this workaround as repeat will only repeat what's inside of the flatMap (not the post call before that but it can do the post call inside it).
3. An AtomicInteger as your index.
4. Change the return type to Flux, collect and cast.

Hope someone will benefit from my headache.

Answer (score 0):

the issue with your code is that you are returning inside the for loop, which causes the function to return immediately after the first iteration of the loop. Instead of returning, you can use the flatMap operator to keep the pipeline going and add the results of each iteration to the subscriptionIds

Comment: The problem is that the flatmap require a return and I don't know how to avoid that. Can you share your solution to avoid it?

Comment: Also I tried a .flatMap after the first flatMap but I don't know how can I repeat that kind of behavior i number of times (the integer value that I use in the first loop result of my first post)

Comment: Ok , i see , you can use also  flatMapMany() and Flux.range() instead of the for loop , You need to replace for loop with  ` Flux.range(1, totalPages)
    .flatMapMany(i ->` and you also need to return ` Mono.just(subscriptionIds)`  after flatMapMany

Comment: thank you I'll try this solution tomorrow morning (here is evening).

Comment: it's not possible to use flatMapMany after Flux.range, it only accept flatMap.

Comment: And not sure why when I use Flux.range it's not even going inside the loop.

Comment: flatMapMany was part of the solution... Flux too... just look at my answer. I cannot accept yours as right but if you edit it (at least with the comment that you made) I will vote yours up since it helped me a little.